# multiple scanf's use issue

Tags: c, string, structure, scanf

I have the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"gestion.h"
#define N 2


void remplissage_info_etudient(Etudiant *E)
{
    int i;
    FILE *fichier = NULL;
    char *test ; 
    fichier = fopen("test.txt", "w");

    if (fichier != NULL)

{
    fputs("nom des etudients  \t CNE \t CNI \t code confidentiel \n ", fichier)  ;

  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        //// lectures des infos 
     printf("entrez le nom et le prenom de l'etudient %d: \n",i);
        scanf(" %s %s",E[i].nom,E[i].prenom); 
        printf("entrez le CNE de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
        scanf(" %d",&(E[i].CNE));
        printf("entrez le CNI de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
        scanf(" %s",E[i].CNI);
        printf("entrez le code confidentiel de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
        scanf(" %d ",&(E[i].Code_confidentiel));
        ///// ecriture ds le fichier 
        fprintf(fichier," %s %s \t",E[i].nom,E[i].prenom);
        fprintf(fichier," %d\t",E[i].CNE);
        fprintf(fichier,"%s\t",E[i].CNI);
        fprintf(fichier,"%d \t \n ",E[i].Code_confidentiel);


  }

        }
    else 
    {
    printf("error") ; 
    }
    fclose(fichier);
}
```

the structure E is declared as:

```
typedef struct Etudiant
{
char nom[64];
char prenom[64];
char adresse[64];
int sexe;
char niveau_scolaire[64];
char CNI[64];
int   Code_confidentiel;
int   CNE;
}Etudiant;
```

when I use the function : remplissage_info_etudient I get some weird error with fprintf function : 
-->in the last call of fprintf it doesn't pass directly to the next line and it ask me to enter another string I don't know what to do Is there a specific rule for multi use of scanf function?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every question tagged `C` that didn't check the return value of `scanf` I would be incomprehensibly rich.

Comment: what I'm supposed to check in scanf returned value ??

Comment: @user45232 First step is always reading the documentation: [`scanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). There you'll see that it returns the number of output items assigned. If it is not what you expect, then you shouldn't continue, because your variables were not assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read using `fgets()`, check `sscanf()` results and limit string width input

```
for(i=0;i<2;)
  char buffer[200];

  printf("entrez le nom et le prenom de l'etudient %d: \n",i);
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  if (2 != sscanf(buffer, "%63s%63s",E[i].nom,E[i].prenom)) continue;

  printf("entrez le CNE de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  if (1 != sscanf(buffer, "%d",&(E[i].CNE)) continue;

  printf("entrez le CNI de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  if (1 != sscanf(buffer, "%63s",E[i].CNI)) continue;

  printf("entrez le code confidentiel de l'etudient %d : \n",i);
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  if (1 != sscanf(bufffer, "%d", &(E[i].Code_confidentiel)) continue;

  ///// ecriture ds le fichier 
  ...
  i++;
}
```

---

Main issue: The space after `"%d"` in `scanf(" %d ",&(E[i].Code_confidentiel));` causes `scanf` to continue looking for input after the the number.  `" "` tell to keep looking for white-space until a subsequent non-white-space is found.

Not checking `scanf()` family of functions invariable leads to trouble.  Check the results and handle accordingly.

Not limiting string width is another problem, use limits like `"%63s"`.

`" "` before most specifiers is usually not needed.  All specifiers, expect `%c %n %[` consume leading white-space anyways.

Comment: @user45232  Note: I was being a bit lazy.  Each `fgets()` should be more like `if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) break;` for if `stdin` is closed, no point in asking for more data.